# SQLite in PCL for windows universal app

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make a library for my windows universal app but no matter what I cannot get SQLite to work in my Portable Class Library so I can use the same code for windows 8.1/windows phone 8.1. I tried this code:

```
var data = await database.CreateTableAsync<MyData>(CreateFlags.None);
```

but I get this exception but I don't understand how to fix this.

A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Additional information: Something went wrong in the build configuration.  This is the bait assembly, which is for referencing by portable libraries, and should never end up part of the app.  Reference the appropriate platform assembly instead.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net
Has anyone used this library that could guide me in this matter?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are adding the parameter CreateFlags.None?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/

Comment: @  Alundra the dreamwalker no not really, I'm just trying to get it to run atm :)

Comment: I'm going to see if I can get that example to run in my PCL.

Comment: Let me know if you have problems with the example

Comment: It works but I still can't use SQLite in my PCL.